# Rotating Point Cloud Data in Bird's-Eye-View Using Rotation Matrix

Tags: python, rotation, point-clouds

I am trying to rotate 3d point cloud data to theta degree using rotation matrix.
The shape of point cloud data that is indicated as 'xyz' in code is (64,2048,3), so there are 131,072 points including x,y,z.
I have tried with 2d rotation matrix (since I want to rotate in bird's eye view).

The 2d rotation matrix that I used is: [image: 2d rotation matrix]

And this is my code for the rotation:

```
def rotation (xyz):
            original_x = []
            original_y = []
            for i in range(64):
                for j in range(2048): 
                    original_x.append(xyz[i][j][0])
                    original_y.append(xyz[i][j][1])
                    
            original = np.matrix.transpose(np.array([original_x,original_y]))
            rotation_2d = [[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)],[np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)]]
            rotated_points = np.matmul(original,rotation_2d)

            return rotated_points
```

The result looks successful from bird's eye view, but not successful from the front view, as it is very messy so it is not possible to understand the data.

I have also tried with 3d rotation matrix with [x,y,z] that is : [image: 3d rotation matrix]

However, the result was exactly the same when 2d rotation matrix was used.

What could be the possible reason? Is there any mistake in the rotation method?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about the issue with the front view? Is the front view better before the data is rotated? Also, note that depending on your graphing method, you might simply be able to specify the viewing angle as an argument to the plotting function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The front view is very messy so that it is not able to identify any object or environment. Looks like points are flying around. Before the rotation, the front view of original data is very clear, so that I can identify objects and environment. I am using point cloud visualization tool 'Cloud Compare' which makes me able to view the data in 3d and I can change the angle.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are rotating the data yourself rather than simply changing the view angle, then?

Comment: It is because I want to normalize the point cloud data. Every time I collect data with Lidar sensor, the angle of the sensor from the target object changes. I want to make the target objects to be on the same angle to the sensor, so that I can label and segment the target objects at the same time.

Comment: The rotation script is doing the rotation that you want (clockwise). If there is a problem with your script, it has to do with how your rotated result is used to build the 3d data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that applies the rotation you're after and a demonstration of this code.

Note that the rotation is applied clockwise. For a counterclockwise rotation, use the transpose of the rotation matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.linalg import block_diag

def rotation(xyz):
    before = xyz.reshape((-1,3))
    rot_3d = block_diag([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)],[np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)]],1)
    after = before @ rot_3d
    return after

theta = 3*np.pi/2
xyz_test = np.random.rand(8,16)
xyz_test = np.stack([xyz_test]*3,axis = -1)
xyz_test += np.random.randn(8,16,3)*.1
original = xyz_test.reshape([8*16,3])
rotated = rotation(xyz_test)

# plt.plot(1,2,3,projection = '3d')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,10), subplot_kw = {"projection":"3d"})
ax.plot3D(*original.T, 'x', ms = 20)
ax.plot3D(*rotated.T, 'x', ms = 20)
```

Sample resulting plot (of cloud and rotated cloud):

[image]